# How to move the description of morphism

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I want to draw a commutative diagram, i completed it,

```
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em, column sep = 2em]
   0\arrow[rr]&&
   D' \arrow[rr,"\sigma_1"] \arrow[dr,dashed, swap,"d'"] \arrow[dd,swap] &&
    D \arrow[dd] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"d"] \arrow[rr,"\sigma_2"]&&
    D'' \arrow[rr]\arrow[dr,dashed ,swap,"d'' "]\arrow[dd] &&0\\
    &0\arrow[rr] && C' \arrow[rr,"\gamma_1"] \arrow[dd]&&
    C \arrow[dd]\arrow[rr,"\gamma_2"]&&
    C''\arrow[dd]\arrow[rr] &&
    0\\
   0\arrow[rr] &&
   B \arrow[rr,"\beta_1"] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial' "] && B \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial "]\arrow[rr,"\beta_2"]&& B''\arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial'' "]\arrow[rr]&&0 \\
    &0\arrow[rr]&& A' \arrow[rr,"\alpha_1"]&& A\arrow[rr,"\alpha_2"]&& A''\arrow[rr]&& 0
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

But I have a small problem that Description of map beta and gamma coincide with the downward map. How to move it a little so it won't be cut by downward line?

Comment: i don't know hoe to add image created by the code, but i shared the code. I will try to add the image asap.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Add as further option `near start`, `near end`, or `pos=`n, where n is a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: could you give an example @gernot

Comment: Just done .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one of the options `near start`, `near end`, `very near start`, `very near end` to the options of `\arrow`. For finer control, use `pos=`*n* instead, where *n* is a number between 0 and 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em, column sep = 2em]
   0\arrow[rr]&&
   D' \arrow[rr,"\sigma_1"] \arrow[dr,dashed, swap,"d'"] \arrow[dd,swap] &&
    D \arrow[dd] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"d"] \arrow[rr,"\sigma_2"]&&
    D'' \arrow[rr]\arrow[dr,dashed ,swap,"d'' "]\arrow[dd] &&0\\
    &0\arrow[rr] && C' \arrow[rr,"\gamma_1",near start] \arrow[dd]&&
    C \arrow[dd]\arrow[rr,"\gamma_2",near start]&&
    C''\arrow[dd]\arrow[rr] &&
    0\\
   0\arrow[rr] &&
   B \arrow[rr,"\beta_1",near start] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial' "] && B \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial "]\arrow[rr,"\beta_2",very near start]&& B''\arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial'' "]\arrow[rr]&&0 \\
    &0\arrow[rr]&& A' \arrow[rr,"\alpha_1"]&& A\arrow[rr,"\alpha_2"]&& A''\arrow[rr]&& 0
    \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh great, Now this is what i'm expected. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Just add a quad to each of the relevant labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em, column sep = 2em]
   0\arrow[rr]&&
   D' \arrow[rr,"\sigma_1"] \arrow[dr,dashed, swap,"d'"] \arrow[dd,swap] &&
    D \arrow[dd] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"d"] \arrow[rr,"\sigma_2"]&&
    D'' \arrow[rr]\arrow[dr,dashed ,swap,"d'' "]\arrow[dd] &&0\\
    &0\arrow[rr] && C' \arrow[rr,"\gamma_1\quad"] \arrow[dd]&&
    C \arrow[dd]\arrow[rr,"\gamma_2\quad"]&&
    C''\arrow[dd]\arrow[rr] &&
    0\\
   0\arrow[rr] &&
   B \arrow[rr,"\beta_1\quad"] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial' "] && B \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial "]\arrow[rr,"\beta_2\quad"]&& B''\arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"\partial'' "]\arrow[rr]&&0 \\
    &0\arrow[rr]&& A' \arrow[rr,"\alpha_1"]&& A\arrow[rr,"\alpha_2"]&& A''\arrow[rr]&& 0
    \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good, Thank you